# How to call ngx-perfect-scrollbar update() and ScrollTop() method in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, perfect-scrollbar

I am using `"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.3.5"`. I am adding the description as "See More" and "See Less" and there is scroll on the page. When performing "See More" and "See Less" click action, perfect Scrollbar is not updating itself and there remains a extra whitespace at the bottom.

## .html

```
<div class="col-12 ps" [perfectScrollbar]="scrollConfig">
<div class="seeMoreContent" *ngIf="seeMore === true">
---
----
---
</div>
<div class="seeLessContent" *ngIf="seeMore === false">
---
----
---
</div>
 <span (click)="updateSeeMore('seeMore')" class="seeMore">
See more</span>
<span (click)="updateSeeMore('seeLess')" class="seeLess">
  See Less
</span>
</div>
```

## .ts

```
scrollConfig = {
    suppressScrollX: false,
    suppressScrollY: false
};

updateSeeMore(type){
if(type === 'seemore'){
 this.seeMore = true;
}else{
 this.seeMore = false;
}
// Want to update the scroll here

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use like this

```
<perfect-scrollbar
                #perfectScroll
                [config]="psConfig"
                [scrollIndicators]="true"
                (psScrollY)="onListScroll()">
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

Inside Component file

```
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface, PerfectScrollbarComponent } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';

@ViewChild('perfectScroll') perfectScroll: PerfectScrollbarComponent;
```

Now you can use this inside your method where you want to update scroll

```
this.perfectScroll.directiveRef.update(); //for update scroll
this.perfectScroll.directiveRef.scrollToTop(offset?, speed?); //for update scroll
```

Comment: But, here I am using it in different way and how should I implement it in above scenario.

Comment: Geeting error as:- Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Comment: My scroll is not working on key press and that is because I do not have focus over the div surrounded by perfect-scrollbar initially. I want the scroll to work with key press without manually setting the focus by mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following ways to your component:

```
import { PerfectScrollbarDirective } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
```

```
@ViewChild(PerfectScrollbarDirective, { static: false }) perfectScrollbarDirectiveRef?: PerfectScrollbarDirective;
```

```
this.perfectScrollbarDirectiveRef.update();
this.perfectScrollbarDirectiveRef.scrollToTop(0, 1);
```